# Apple Mach-O Linker Error With No Solution

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I am getting an error stating the following and tried many modifications with my current coding with no solution. Please let me know what I must proceed to do, much appreciated.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
          objc-class-ref in HomeController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you have a class name `ViewController` in AppDelegate and HomeController?

Comment: I did, initially the LoginViewController was named ViewController but as I replaced I continue to get errors, here is the code.

-(void)rootViewController
{
    LoginViewController *homeController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Check in HomeViewController is defined properly in HomeviewController interface and implementation file(check spelling too) and Homeviewcontroller.m is added in Target...and also same for App delegate

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class named "ViewController" is added to your target and being compiled.

Comment: I think it was being mistaken in which I tried fixing.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean ? But you are getting a linker error. So the problem must either be that you don't have the ViewController.m compiling in your target or there could be a typo when you define your interface/implementation in your ViewController.h and ViewController.m file.

Comment: If my Viewcontroller is essentially not named "ViewController.m" is what your saying might be the initial problem?

Comment: I'd have to double check that. It might be ok if your file is named differently. But it's a good practice to name your file after your interface.